# url filtering/whitelisting for apache before it reaches https port

Tags: apache2, url

I am running an Apache web server on 80 and 443 in Ubuntu 22.04, and I would like to allow only hosted subdomains, invalid subdomains should be blocked before Apache serves default certificate for invalid subdomains(which results in  SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN).

Ex: I have a wildcard DNS like *.example.com,valid subdomains are like app1.example.com app2.example.com, for which virtual hosts are created in Apache config.

Now if any user hits xyz.example.com, the connection should be blocked (giving connection times out error in browsers).

I cant have wildcard SSL certificate for some reason, and **browser gives SSL warning error** for non existing subdomains!, which I dont want and **instead should get connection timed out**.

Is this possible with Apache itself? or any simple workaround?. I tried with haproxy but no luck!.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What do you mean by "blocked"? Do you want the HTTP request to immediately close? Do you want to redirect somewhere else? Depending on the complexity you seek, the configuration files in `sites-available` can be configured to permit only the domains you want.